# Centering a list item on the screen when selected in Android?

Tags: java, android, listview, centering

I have a listView and a timer iterates through each list item. Ideally I'd like to have the currently selected item to automatically center in the listView. I've played around with smoothScrollToPosition() but am lost on how to work out centering the current item.

My corrected code (thanks to Matej Spili):

```
// Smooth scroll the list item 
try {
scrollView.smoothScrollBy(scrollView.getChildAt().getTop(‌​) - (scrollView.getHeight() / 2) + (scrollView.getChildAt().getHeight() / 2), 1500);
} 
catch (NullPointerException e)
{ 
System.out.println("NULL POINTER DEALT WITH");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get the height of the ListView using **getHeight**, which returns the height of the ListView in pixels.

Then, get the height of the row's View using the same method.

Then, use **setSelectionFromTop** and pass in half of the ListView's height minus half of the row's height.

Something like:

```
int h1 = mListView.getHeight();
int h2 = v.getHeight();

mListView.setSelectionFromTop(position, h1/2 - h2/2);
```

Or, instead of doing the math, you might just pick a constant for the offset from the top, but I would think it might be more fragile on different devices since the second argument for setSelectionFromTop appears to be in pixels rather than device independent pixels.

I haven't tested this code, but it should work as long as your rows are all roughly the same height.

Or in one line:

```
scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, selectedView.getTop() - (scrollView.getHeight() / 2) + (selectedView.getHeight() / 2), 0);
```

Comment: Thank you, got me right on track. :) I had to use a try block as I was getting a null pointer error on the last items.

My final code is:

`
                // Smooth scroll the list item
                try {
scrollView.smoothScrollBy(scrollView.getChildAt(Object.getCurrentStep()).getTop() - (scrollView.getHeight() / 2) + (scrollView.getChildAt(Object.getCurrentStep()).getHeight() / 2), 1500);
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    System.out.println("NULL POINTER DEALT WITH");
                }`

Comment: i am glad that i could help ... please edit your question put it there .. also please vote up my question :) good luck and have fun :)

Comment: I'm new to this, have added the solution but don't have the rep yet to upvote, sorry. :(

Comment: Thanks for the exception comment @Mint_Sauce!  Nice add and +1!  I ended up using smoothScrollBy to get what i wanted as well. My cells are different sized.